# formulario no envía correo

Tags: php, email

Buenas tardes esto tratando de enviar un un correo desde el formulario de mi pagina web pero no lo envía mi formulario es

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="mu-contact-left">
     <div id="form-messages"></div>
     <form id="ajax-contact" action="testmail.php" method="post" class="mu-contact-form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control name" placeholder="Nombre" id="name" name="name" required="required">

        <input type="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="Correo Electronico" id="mail" name="email"
           required="required">

        <input type="text" class="form-control phone" placeholder="Telefono" id="phone" name="phone"
           required="required">

        <textarea class="form-control message" placeholder="Mensaje" id="message" name="message"
           required="required"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="mu-send-msg-btn"><span>ENVIAR</span></button>
     </form>
  </div>
```

mi código PHP es

```
?php
   //Reseteamos variables a 0.
   $nombre = $email = $phone = $mensaje = $para = $headers = $msjCorreo = NULL;

   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      //Obtenemos valores input formulario
      $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $phone = $_POST['phone'];   
      $mensaje = $_POST['message'];
      $para = 'johanb7070@gmail.com';

      //Creamos cabecera.
      $headers = 'From' . " " . $email . "\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";

      //Componemos cuerpo correo.
      $msjCorreo = "Nombre: " . $nombre;
      $msjCorreo .= "\r\n";
      $msjCorreo .= "Email: " . $email;
      $msjCorreo .= "\r\n";
      $msjCorreo .= "Asunto: " . $phone;
      $msjCorreo .= "\r\n";
      $msjCorreo .= "Mensaje: " . $mensaje;
      $msjCorreo .= "\r\n";

    if (mail($para, $phone, $msjCorreo, $headers)) {
         echo "&lt;script language='javascript'&gt;
            alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');
         &lt;/script&gt;";
    } else {
         echo "&lt;script language='javascript'&gt;
            alert('fallado');
         &lt;/script&gt;";
    }
  }
?
```

También intente con PHP Mailer pero tampoco me funciono y PHP Mailer instalado directamente desde el servidor

```
?php
       //Reseteamos variables a 0.
       $nombre = $email = $subject = $mensaje = $para = NULL;

       if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

          //Obtenemos valores input formulario
          $nombre = $_POST['name'];
          $email = $_POST['email'];
          $subject = $_POST['phone'];   
          $mensaje = $_POST['message'];
          $para = 'johanb7070@gmail.com';


          //Compones nuestro correo electronico

          //Incluimos libreria PHPmailer (deberas descargarlo).
          require'class.phpmailer.php';

          //Nuevo correo electronico.
          $mail = new PHPMailer;
          //Caracteres.
          $mail-&gt;CharSet = 'UTF-8';

          //De dirección correo electrónico y el nombre
          $mail-&gt;From = "contacto@iglefiel.com";
          $mail-&gt;FromName = "iglefiel.com";

          //Dirección de envio y nombre.
          $mail-&gt;addAddress($para, $nombre);
          //Dirección a la que responderá destinatario.
          $mail-&gt;addReplyTo("contacto@iglefiel.com","johan");

          //BCC -&gt;  incluir copia oculta de email enviado.
          $mail-&gt;addBCC("contacto@iglefiel.com");

          //Enviar codigo HTML o texto plano.
          $mail-&gt;isHTML(true);

          //Titulo email.
          $mail-&gt;Subject = "Nuestro titulo";
          //Cuerpo email con HTML.
          $mail-&gt;Body = "
                  &lt;h1&gt;Envio libreria PHPMailer&lt;/h1&gt;

                  Nombre: $nombre&lt;br /&gt; 
                  Email: $email &lt;br /&gt;
                  Asunto: $subject &lt;br /&gt;
                 Mensaje: $mensaje &lt;br /&gt;

          "; 

        //Comprobamos el envio.
        if(!$mail-&gt;send()) {                   
            echo "&lt;script language='javascript'&gt;
                alert('fallado');
             &lt;/script&gt;";
        } else {
            echo "&lt;script language='javascript'&gt;
                alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');
             &lt;/script&gt;";
        } 
      }
    ?
```

me dieron estos pasos de Hostinger

Instalar PHPMailer es bastante simple, especialmente si tienes Composer instalado. Si estás utilizando Hostinger, no necesitas preocuparte por esto ya que viene preinstalado con todos nuestros planes de alojamiento.

No obstante, si necesitas instalar PHPMailer manualmente, debes conectar tu cuenta de alojamiento a través del terminal SSH. Sigue estos pasos:

Descarga e instala el cliente PuTTY SSH.
Ve a tu panel de hPanel, busca y haz clic en Acceso SSH en la sección Avanzado.
Toma nota de la información de acceso SSH. Necesitarás la dirección IP SSH, puerto, nombre de usuario y contraseña.
Abre PuTTY, luego configura tu IP SSH y el puerto correspondiente.
donde ya esta instalado

pero tampoco me llegan los correos a la dirección indicada ni aparecen en la bandeja de SPAM gracias por su ayuda , feliz día

Comment: Buenas, el código va como texto con formato `{ }` . No se deben usar imagenes.

Comment: Hola! Ya que vas a editar tu pregunta para poner el código como texto, puedes aprovechar y revisar si en los logs de PHP hay algún mensaje relacionado con los intentos de envío (para que lo pongas en tu pregunta, también como texto).

Comment: Donde defines el servidor SMTP y el user/pass para enviar correo?

Comment: ¿Has depurado algo? Por ejemplo, pon un `var_dump($_POST);` al principio de tu script PHP y dinos qué datos muestra. ¿Revisaste la carpeta SPAM del correo al que intentas enviar el email? ¿Revisaste el log de errores de PHP? Te acabo de señalar tres herramientas de depuración que no mencionas en tu pregunta y que te pueden ayudar a encontrar rápidamente el problema.